# Не работает click() в chrome 56v

Tags: javascript, dojo

Не работает переопределенный onClick() (заходит в if, вызывает click(), но ничего не происходит) в браузере Chrome версии 56:

```
onClick: function onClick(payload) {
  if (this.selectFile != null) {
    $(this.selectFile.domNode). //Это input
      click();
  }
}
```

Но тот же самый код работает в firefox.

Comment: А полный код можно увидеть?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Попробуй `$(this.selectFile.domNode).on('click' function(){});`

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?